# flashed wrong firmware on netgear fvs336g v3

Tags: flash, firmware, netgear-router

Netgear FVS336G V3 received latest firmware dedicated to FVS336G V1

It doesn't seem to boot up properly. DHCP does not assign IP address, manual configuration doesn't allow to connect to the device.

I did factory reset but I think it just erased my configuration.

Is there anything I can do to save this device?

Comment: Are you able to re-flash to the prior version?

Comment: @John - unfortunately, I can't connect to the device at all.

Comment: If a reset did not work and if you cannot connect to the router, then it has been bricked. You will need to replace it.

Comment: that was my assumption but wanted to check if anyone has any better idea what to do before I'll throw it away. Thanks John!

Comment: Try the Netgear article [How do I upload firmware to my NETGEAR router using TFTP from the Microsoft Windows Command Prompt?](https://kb.netgear.com/000059634/How-to-upload-firmware-to-a-NETGEAR-router-using-Windows-TFTP)